# Determine what current delta/span is

Tags: xcode, swift, mapkit

When the annotation is being tapped, I center that annotation on the map, no problem. The problem is that if the user have zoomed in or out from the original zoomlevel I would like that zoomlevel.

This is how I center the map. But again, how do I get the current span?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.1, 1.1) //Get current span?
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: view.annotation.coordinate, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply ask for the current `MKMapView.region` and set a new center coordinate on that:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    var region = mapView.region  // get the current region
    region.center = view.annotation.coordinate

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)    
}
```

Comment: Of course. Monday misstake even if it's Tuesday. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you!! for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically address how to center around a lat/lon while preserving the span, allowing the user to drill down and up but always centering on the point, here is some code that I used.  This recenters the pin when an action is performed on the map.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {


        //Get the location that I am going to center on from a variable with apreviously set location.  
        //This is what I want to center on
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(

            //getPropertyLocation.latitude/longitude already set to CLLocationDegrees in a prior process.
            latitude: self.getPropertyLocation.latitude ,
            longitude: self.getPropertyLocation.longitude
        )

        // Get the span that the mapView is set to by the user. "propertyMapView" is the MKMapView in this example.
        let span = self.propertyMapView.region.span


        // Now setup the region based on the lat/lon of the property and retain the span that already exists.
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

        //Center the view with some animation.
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


}
```